# How to Apply CSS to Facebook Login Button

Tags: php, html, css, facebook, twitter-bootstrap

Wondering how to use CSS to push down the facebook login button just a few pixels so that it would align with everything else on the navbar.

[image]

Here is the code for the navbar with the login button included.

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="404.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:window.open('contact.php', 'Contact Us', 'width=500,height=500');">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Use</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><?php if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) { echo $_SESSION['name']; } ?></li>
                </ul>
            <li><?php if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) { } else {  ?><div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></div></li><?php } ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use this css code

```
   .nav .fb-login-button{ 
     margin-top:4px; /* or whater ever you want for  margin top */
    }
```

and also you can use this

```
   .nav .fb-login-button{ 
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Give **margin** to the **li** of Like Button

**Example :-**  margin-top: 9px;

Answer (score 0):

you could just target the facebook icon directly and a css rule of

```
position:relative;
top:the position you want
```